# Unable to print dynamically allocated pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Hi since I'm learning C and C++ I will be making a lot of mistakes while using the coding terminology, Question is:

Why am I unable to printf the value of *p? Doesn't malloc return a NULL pointer; so why does it give segmentation fault?

I read that null pointer does not compare equal to an unallocated pointer.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
    {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));

    p= 100;

    printf("Value of p is: %d \n",p);
    printf("value of *p is: %d \n",*p);
    printf("Value of &p is: %d \n",&p);


    }
```

Output in terminal:

```
rtpl@rtpl-desktop:~/Desktop$ ./practice_output 
Value of p is: 100 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Output in terminal when second `printf` statement is commented out:

```
rtpl@rtpl-desktop:~/Desktop$ ./practice_output 
Value of p is: 100 
Value of &p is: -1514709824
```

Also I'm pretty sure I have put an incorrect title to the question: Please tell me what I should change it to

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled! `*p = 100`. `p = 100` isn't even legal C, it would convert integer to a pointer, but standardwise it needs a cast.

Comment: `printf("Value of p is: %d \n",p);`..Pure UB.

Comment: What is the meaning of UB

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: `p= 100;` assigns the address `100` to `p` (which is way down in the *system reserved memory region*) -- guaranteed to cause a segfault when you try and access it.... (not to mention causes a memory leak by loss of the original pointer address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check return value of `malloc` and `*p=100` you want to do. Otherwise you are changing a pointer's value. And having a memory leak.

Value of `p` should be printed with `%p`. `printf("%p",p);`

Also `free` the dynamically allocated memory after you are done working with it.

---

```
int main()
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if( p == NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in allocation");
       exit(1);
    }
    *p= 100;

    printf("Value of p is: %p \n",p);
    printf("value of *p is: %d \n",*p);
    printf("Value of &p is: %p \n",&p);
    free(p);

}
```

--

Also when you want to assign something to a pointer variable you have to cast it to proper type.

```
int *p;
p = (int*)0x12f3ff;
```

Accessing some out of memory address or using wrong format specifier leads to Undefined behavior.

Comment: okay but can I not do p=100?

Comment: @vedantgala.: You don't want to change the value of a pooiter variable with a `something-you-like` value.

Comment: Removed previous erroneous comment. Please flag this "no longer needed ".

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with %d its the problem in `p = 100`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
    {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *p= 100;

    printf("Value of p is: %d \n",p);
    printf("value of *p is: %d \n",*p);
    printf("Value of &p is: %d \n",&p);


    }
```

Comment: Printing a pointer with `%d` is actually one of the big problems here. Most notably, it will not work on any mainstream PC, where `int` is 32 bit signed but pointers are 64 bit unsigned. The OP should be using `%p`.

Comment: i tried in my 32 bit its working. Thanks for the infromation @Lundin